# Using Apache common-cli to parse arguments

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

Apache common-cli has a example on its web site for `ls` command:

```
options.addOption( "a", "all", false, "do not hide entries starting with ." );
options.addOption( "A", "almost-all", false, "do not list implied . and .." );
options.addOption( "b", "escape", false, "print octal escapes for nongraphic " + "characters" );
options.addOption( OptionBuilder.withLongOpt( "block-size" )
                                .withDescription( "use SIZE-byte blocks" )
                                .hasArg()
                                .withArgName("SIZE")
                                .create() );
```

This shows help like this:

```
-a, --all                  do not hide entries starting with .
-A, --almost-all           do not list implied . and ..
-b, --escape               print octal escapes for nongraphic characters
    --block-size=SIZE      use SIZE-byte blocks
```

1. When I write this code, it shows `--block-size <SIZE>`. I want to show something like this: `-z,--block-size=SIZE`(not just
   long option).
2. what is the difference of `PosixParser` and `GnuParser`? I changed
   them in the code, I didn't observed any difference.
3. When I provide wrong option for example `h` it doesn't `throw` any `ParseException`. The program starts and finishes normally.

Comment: Provide a "z" short option, then; there isn't one now, so why would it show one?

Comment: There isn't `z` option in main example. I want `z` option to be showed too. I want to know How can I write that `z` is also available.

Comment: Did you read any of the docs it APIs? Or just try something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The block size option in the example has only a long format, that's why there is no short option shown. If you add a short alias you'll get the result you expect
2. `PosixParser` and `GnuParser` are deprecated in the latest version of Commons CLI. A new unified parser is available as `DefaultParser`. The posix parser had the ability to parse concatenated short options, something like `tar -zxvf foo.tar.gz`.
3. Extra options are either handled as arguments to the application or trigger an exception, depending of the value of the `stopAtNonOption` parser parameter.