# How to build CLI from Maven project like mvn, gradle etc?

Tags: java, maven, command-line-interface

For instance I have a Maven project called blabla, and I want to control it by CLI like mvn (Maven) or gradle.(Examples, `$ mvn clean install, $ gradle init` etc).

And instead of launching

```
$ java BlaBla start
```

or

```
$ java BlaBla stop
```

etc

I want to do like this:

```
$ blabla start
$ blabla status
$ blabla stop
```

etc.

Is there any ready solution for maven projects?

Comment: you could create a bat or some other script, I presume.

Comment: @Stultuske From scratch?

Comment: why not? how many lines of code do you think you would need for that?

Comment: What if I don't know bash?

Comment: nothing wrong with learning a bit about it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file

Comment: Did you consider just writing a script? Bash / whatever...

Comment: @Stultuske It seems you are really right, the only way of achieving this is to create bash script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take a look at the [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) which can create a script based on the name and supports creating a shell and a bat variant...

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Is there something similar for gradle as well?

Answer (score 1):

For Maven, take a look at the [Maven Exec Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html), you can do something like:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            ...
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.mycompany.BlaBla</mainClass>
          <arguments>
            <argument>start</argument>
            ...
          </arguments>
          <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
              <key>myproperty</key>
              <value>myvalue</value>
            </systemProperty>
            ...
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   ...
</project>
```

You can then run something like `mvn exec:java`

There is something similar with Gradle via the [Exec Task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html).

Though I don't know the specific use case related to your question, it may be a better idea to use a bash script or another way specifically designed to *run software*. Maven and Gradle are *build automation* tools, their primary goal is not to run your program but compile your code, run tests and create artifact (among other things).

Answer (score 1):

Use the library [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/). It's a library there you can build OptionLists (arguments, parameters, etc.) like this.

```
 package CLi;

   import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
   import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
   import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;
   import org.apache.commons.cli.HelpFormatter;
   import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
   import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;
   import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
   import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

 public class CLi 
   {
 /** 
        * @see http://www.thinkplexx.com/blog/simple-apache-commons-cli-example-            java-command-line-arguments-parsing
        * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10798945
        * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166630/apache-commons-cli-   not-parsing-as-expected
        * 
        * Link to Java-Library:
        * @see https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/   
        */

   /**
    * Variables
    */
   private String[] args;
   private Options options = new Options();
   private HelpFormatter formater;
   private CommandLineParser parser;
   private CommandLine cmd;
   private Scanner console; 
   private String cmdLine; 
   private boolean noParam;

   /**
    * Constructor.
    * @param args - The command-line arguments.
   */
   public CLi(String[] args) 
   {
       this.args = args;
       buildCLIOptions();
   }

  public void parse() throws Exception
  {
    if(args.length == 0)
    {
        noParam = true;
        args = scanParams();
    }
    else
    {
        try 
        {
            parser = new DefaultParser();

            cmd = null;
            cmd = parser.parse(options, args);      

            /**
             * Print help.
             */
            if (cmd.hasOption("help"))
            {
                noParam = false;
                help();
            }

            /**
             * Shutdown.
             */
            if (cmd.hasOption("exit")) 
            {
                noParam = false;
                System.exit(0);     
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public void help() throws Exception
{
    /**
     * This prints out some help
     */
    formater = new HelpFormatter();
    formater.printHelp("Main", options);
    System.out.println(" ");
    noParam = true;
    scanParams();
}

/**
 * Scan params.
 * @return the Parameters
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public String[] scanParams() throws Exception 
{
    System.out.println("Ready... Waiting for input...:");
    System.out.println(" ");

    console = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(noParam)
    {
        cmdLine = console.nextLine();

        args = cmdLine.replace(" -", " #-").split(" #");

        parse();
    }

    console.close();

    return args;
}

public void buildCLIOptions()
{
    options.addOption("exit", "exit", false, "Exiting application.");
    options.addOption("help", "help", false, "show help.");
}
}
```

In the Main class do:

```
public class Main
{       
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        CLi console = new CLi(args);
        console.parse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very useful library, thanks. But I will need anyway bash script for launching from command line as I want. and I decided to create it.